# Why is PLINQ slower than LINQ for this code?

Tags: .net-4.0, parallel-processing, plinq

First off, I am running this on a dual core 2.66Ghz processor machine. I am not sure if I have the .AsParallel() call in the correct spot. I tried it directly on the range variable too and that was still slower. I don't understand why...

Here are my results:

Process non-parallel 1000 took 146 milliseconds

Process parallel 1000 took 156 milliseconds

Process non-parallel 5000 took 5187 milliseconds

Process parallel 5000 took 5300 milliseconds

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace DemoConsoleApp
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      ReportOnTimedProcess(
        () => GetIntegerCombinations(),
        "non-parallel 1000");

      ReportOnTimedProcess(
        () => GetIntegerCombinations(runAsParallel: true),
        "parallel 1000");

      ReportOnTimedProcess(
        () => GetIntegerCombinations(5000),
        "non-parallel 5000");

      ReportOnTimedProcess(
        () => GetIntegerCombinations(5000, true),
        "parallel 5000");

      Console.Read();
    }

    private static List<Tuple<int, int>> GetIntegerCombinations(
      int iterationCount = 1000, bool runAsParallel = false)
    {
      IEnumerable<int> range = Enumerable.Range(1, iterationCount);

      IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> integerCombinations =
        from x in range
        from y in range
        select new Tuple<int, int>(x, y);

      return runAsParallel
               ? integerCombinations.AsParallel().ToList()
               : integerCombinations.ToList();
    }

    private static void ReportOnTimedProcess(
      Action process, string processName)
    {
      var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
      stopwatch.Start();
      process();
      stopwatch.Stop();

      Console.WriteLine("Process {0} took {1} milliseconds",
                        processName, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's slightly slower because PLINQ has a certain overhead (threads, scheduling, etc) so you have to pick carefully what you will parallelize. This particular code you're benchmarking isn't really worth parallelizing, you have to parallelize over tasks with significant load, otherwise the overhead will weight more than the benefits of parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of your execution time here is likely going to be in actually creating the list, via the `ToList()` method.  This will have to perform several memory allocations, resizing the list and so on.  You're also not gaining much of a benefit from parallelizing here because the final operation has to be synchronized (you're building a single list on the output).

Try doing something significantly more complex/expensive in the parallel segment, like prime factorization, and increasing the number of iterations to the hundreds of thousands (5000 is a *very* small number to use when profiling).  You should start to see the difference then.

Also make sure that you're profiling in release mode; all too often I see attempts to profile in debug mode, and the results from that will not be accurate.

Comment: The code in my sample actually would create 25 million combinations of tuples when the iteration count is set to 5000 (5000*5000)

I think I see the issue being that each logical iteration is too small to parallelize anyways. Thanks!